# Serial communication between two arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, communication

I am trying to write a Serial read function. That function will give me a data between '#' (start character) and '*' (end character). I tried to write it and it looks like it is kinda work but not perfectly. The problem is that:

I have two arduino. One of these send "MARCO" and other arduino read it. If the readed data is "MARCO" it is write to serial monitor "MARCOCORRECT" else it is write to serial monitor the readed data. Normally it must just write "MARCOCORRECT" because I only send "MARCO" but it don't. It writes something else too. I tried lower baud rate too but it is still same. How can I fix it?

**Sender Code**

```
#define BAUD_RATE 38400

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
}
String readed = "";
void loop()
{
  String readed;
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    readed += Serial.read();
  }

  Serial.println("#MARCO*");

}
```

**Reader Code**

```
#define BAUD_RATE 38400
#define MSG_START '#'
#define MSG_END '*'

String readed;
char readedChar;
bool msgStart = false;

String serialReadFunc()
{
  readedChar = '0';
  readed = "";
  while (Serial.available() > 0 || msgStart)
  {
    if (readedChar == MSG_START)
    {
      msgStart = true;
    }
    readedChar = (char)Serial.read();

    if (readedChar == MSG_END)
    {
      msgStart = false;
      break;
    }

    if (msgStart)
    {
      readed += readedChar;
    }
  }
  return readed;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
}

void loop()
{
  if (serialReadFunc() == "MARCO")
  {
    Serial.println("MARCOCORRECT");
  }
  else
    Serial.println(readed);
  
}
```

**Console Image On Proteus**

[Console Image Proteus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST8mi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're having synchronization issues. I may be wrong, though, and I'm unable to test it at the moment.

I'd recommend trying to insert a delay on the sender, like so:

```
String readed;
while (Serial.available() > 0)
{
  readed += Serial.read();
}
delay(10);
Serial.println("#MARCO*");
```

It would also be interesting to see the return value of the reader *Serial.available()*. Again, not 100% sure, but I believe the buffer may be full ([the buffer holds 64 bytes](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/)).